# I'm having trouble transcribing a snippet of R code into Python

Tags: python, r, converters

I'm transcribing some R code into Python, and I'm having trouble in this exact block.
Where do I select columns from a table. Can you help me please?

```
dataacumulado <-  data_competencia %m-% months(1)

caminhoplanilhaauxiliar <- "0. Tabela_improcedencia_cluster.xlsx"
caminhoacumulado <- paste0(getwd(),"/","acumulado_",dataacumulado,".rds")
caminhoacumuladonovo <- paste0(getwd(),"/","acumulado_",data_competencia,".rds")
caminhoprocessosencerrados <- paste0(getwd(),"/","processosencerrados_",dataacumulado,".rds")
caminhoprocessosencerradosnovo <- paste0(getwd(),"/","processosencerrados_",data_competencia,".rds")
fechamentoenergisa <- paste0(getwd(),"/","fechamento_energisa_")
fechamentoescritorios <- paste0(getwd(),"/","fechamento_")#Lendo a planilha Excel no R - ***Mudar arquivo para mês de fechamento atual****
fechamento <- setDT(read_xlsx(caminhoexcel))
```

Comment: this code is just constructing file paths and importing an excel data set, where does selecting columns from a table come in?

Comment: Yes, it is linked to a table. I just need the first way about transcribing this column reading.

Comment: so your question is how to import an excel sheet into python?